# ん replacing ない for group 1 verbs (いちだん)

Tags: word-choice

We can replace ない with ん is what I read, but I have only ever seen it in group 2 verbs(ごだん). For example: 知らん、ならん. The question is, is it possible to use it in group 1 verbs（いちだん）? For example: 諦めん?

Also, I read that it is not possible to modify a verb ending with ん. But is it possible to add a ぞ、ぜ、よ？For example: 諦めんぞ

Comment: Where did you read that verbs ending with ん cannot be modified? They can, but it is dialectal. For example 食べんで=食べないで,　食べんかった=食べなかった…

Comment: @a20 For example: 食べられん魚を食べちゃった is grammatically incorrect because 食べられん cannot modify a clause is what I read. Is that not the case?

Comment: I see nothing wrong with that sentence. I should add though that I am not too familiar with how ん-ending is used in standard Japanese. It might be useful if you add your source, where have you read all this?

Comment: @a20 http://www.guidetojapanese.org/learn/grammar/negativeverbs2#A_casual_masculine_type_of_negative_that_ends_in

Comment: okay, my feeling is that the information in your link is simply incorrect. It might be true that in Tokyo, only old men use it and that they do not use it when modifying other words, but at least in Hakata we use it daily in such ways. Maybe someone more fluent in standard japanese and Tokyo sociolects could comment on this.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes you can say ん instead of ない with ichidan verbs. You can say 諦めん, 食べん or even 見ん, 着ん, 出ん.

> But is it possible to add a ぞ、ぜ、よ？ For example: 諦めんぞ

That's also possible, but they may result in an unexpected ambiguity if used with ichidan verbs. んぞ/んぜ/んよ is also a colloquial variation of るぞ/るぜ/るよ, respectively. Thus, 諦めんぞ may mean both 諦めないぞ ("I won't give up") and 諦めるぞ ("Let's give up now") depending on the context. If I understand correctly, this ambiguity does not happen with godan verbs: 走らんぞ (走らないぞ; "I won't run") vs 走んぞ (走るぞ; "Let's run!")

Comment: Why is it only ichidan verbs that has ambiguous meaning when we append a ぞ?

Comment: @Newbie Most godan verbs do not end with る in the first place. Some do end with る (走る, 切る, etc), but ... did you see the last sentence in my answer?

Comment: Why would a る verb cause ambiguity? For example: Why would 食べんぞ mean "Let's eat"? I probably lack the grammar knowledge to see why it means "Let's eat" as opposed to "I won't eat". I do understand that 食べるぞ would mean Let's eat" though". I saw your last sentence but didn't really get how 走んぞ = (走るぞ. Judging by what you said, I get the feeling that 食べんぞ can either mean 食べるぞ or 食べないぞ? I don't know the grammar "rules" for this but would appreciate if you could point me to the name of this rule so I can look into it

Comment: @Newbie Didn't I say るぞ can contract to んぞ in my answer? That's the rule you've missed. 食べるぞ can become 食べんぞ, and 走るぞ can become 走んぞ. 食べないぞ can become 食べんぞ, too.