# Trouble understanding a sentence, notably 渡さんぞ

Tags: grammar, sentence

> 「積み荷は渡さんぞ、この泥棒めが！」

I have trouble with two parts:

1. 渡さんぞ, what is the idea for this construction, I just don't understand. It seems like it's coming from 渡す and some kind of mix between the んだ form and ぞ.
2. 泥棒め, why use め after the noun. Does it have the same function as め after adjectives to say "some kind of", if it does why every lessons only talk about adjectives?

I think it translates to something like "I'm carrying a cargo, you thief!" or something like that but I don't understand the grammar involved.

Comment: I think 渡さん is supposed to be a name, and ぞ is a sentence ending particle

Comment: @maritsm I thought about that possibility but it would be an unlikely coincidence that the name has 渡 in it when talking about a thief and a cargo.

Comment: It could also be a colloquial version of 渡さない, in a similar way to how 分からない is shortened to 分からん

Comment: Related or duplicate: https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/76884/9831 (regarding んぞ), https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/60514/9831 (regarding めが)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I did more digging and I understand it now.

1. It seems like 渡さん is indeed a shortened version of 渡さない. According to this [thread](https://www.japanesepod101.com/forum/viewtopic.php?t=5344), you will sound old and formal if you use it, which corresponds to the story since it's an old merchant carrying some kind of caravan.
2. According to this [post](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/23515/meaning-behind-adding-%E3%82%81-after-someones-name), "め is a suffix of contempt when attached to a noun or another person's name".

With all this in mind, I can confidently say the translation would be: "**I won't hand the cargo to you, stupid thief!**". I believe that last が is for the subject, but it's put at the end to make emphasis on the thief.

Comment: Very close, but for this が, see: https://japanese.stackexchange.com/a/72075/5010